# Cant print twig array

Tags: javascript, php, twig

I have a twig array i get from a hook, when i dump(array) the array it returns this array:

```
array:1 [
  0 => array:2 [
    "Key1" => "Value1"
    "Key2" => "Value2"
  ]
]
```

This is how i dump it:

```
<div> {{ dump(array) }} </div>
```

But when i try to print this it returns Nothing:

```
<div> {{ array }} </div>
```

I also am trying to convert it to a javascript array like this but it returns null:

```
var test = {{ itm|json_encode() }};
console.log(test);
```

Comment: Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63808906/edit) your existing question in order to provide more information/updates about the problem

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. The linked answer "could" be used to convert from PHP to JS array syntax (or simply pass a pre-generated JS string into the template). But Twig also has filters, which might suit better, eg. `{{ data|json }}` or `{% set var = data|json %}`.

Comment: Not sure why u'r saying, anyway if you print an array like that, the output will be [Array](https://twigfiddle.com/fkrjbs), not nothing. Make sure u enable debug so you can see any errors